# how to write code for transfer data from internal memory via SPI Master to 2 slave

Tags: embedded, avr, atmega, atmel

I receive data from USB to the internal memory of Atxmega 128A1

```
    if ( (SWITCHPORTL.IN & PIN1_bm) == 0 )
    {
        j = 0;
        while (j < NUM_BYTES)
        {
            // Wait till there is unread data in the receive buffer
            while((USART.STATUS & USART_RXCIF_bm) == 0 ){};
            // Read out the received data
            __far_mem_write(j+SDRAM_ADDR, USART.DATA);
            if (j == (NUM_BYTES-1))
            {
                // Toggle LED 1
                LEDPORT.OUTTGL = PIN1_bm;
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
```

How to write code for transfer data from internal memory via SPI Master to two slaves such that odd and even byte of data should be send separately to two slaves? How to initiate master to two slaves(multiple slaves)?

Comment: That very much depends on the frame format required by the slaves. You have to read the databooks. Come back if you have any **specific** question with your code.

Comment: @Olaf sorry... i have to post the approach. but unable to post in coded manner as i am new here. can you help me out

Comment: Take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Your here longer than I am.

Comment: @Olaf ya that is fine. no arguments. sorry for inconvenience. i couldn't  find the right way. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible mostly when both the slave will understand data in a similar format, as in have same configuration for CPOL and CPHA. You can select one particular slave by enabling the CS pin respectively. So, your code can look like:

```
initMaster();
selectSlave1(); //Make CS1 low and CS2 high
spiTransmit(data1); //transmit odd byte
selectSlave2(); //Make CS2 low and CS1 high
spiTransmit(data2); //transmit even byte
```

Comment: Will likely not work, as at the moment you switch selects, the SPI is very likely still busy shifting. Also, you have to dispose the received data in-between. Further: once you select Slave2, you have both selects active (unless `selectSlave2()` implies "deselect slave 1"). Also: What if the devices require an address before the data? Which format? ... Datasheets required (but that would go too far for this site).

Comment: - I generally implement spiTransmit() to make sure the sending is complete, by checking for this flag: while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)));
- You are right, seletSlaven() - deselects all slave and then selects slave n
- And yes, if address is required, that needs to be provided too.

Comment: I think the question just involves multiplexing over SPI, for 2 different slaves, and that seems doable.
You might have to just configure them separately, wait for initialization to be completed and then just send one byte and move to other.

Comment: @Olaf Should i  set first slave and read even bytes to the first slave from  the internal memory and then force the first slave to deactivate. further start the second slave and do repeat the same?

Comment: @SijoJohn, Please understand this is no tutorial site and I cannot give training here.

Comment: @Apoorv: Not sure (I'm not that familar with AVR), but if the SPI is double-buffered, that might fail if that flag is just "transmit buffer ready". I would rename the functions then. It is just not clear from their names, so you need to supply more in your answer (the answer should not leave such questions open)..

Comment: Is it possible to split the SPIC.DATA into SPIC.DATA % 2 = =0 for even and else odd transfer these files to the two slave selects? 
Otherwise is it possible to do the same with defined variable SDRAM_ADDR?

Answer (score 0):

Since both slaves are connected to the same bus that only can be transfer one data at a time you have two options to choose from:

1. implement a simple protocol so that each slave does know, which byte belongs to it. (example: one byte header with 6 bit length and 2 bit receiver code or (1 - slave 1, 2 slave 2 - 3 both slaves even/odd)
2. use slave select pins and transfer a byte and make sure you do not send the next and deselect the first receiver until the old was send (calculate clock cycles how long would it take and `nop` them or use them for other usefull stuff))